# How to read data pointer from within a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

In my C application which is using a closed library, I get a callback when a receive action is finished, and in this callback, the framework I use do this

```
void callbackRX(event_t ID, callbackData_t *callbackData_p){
    rxData_t *dataPacket = (rxData_t *)(callbackData_p->params.rxInfo.dataInfo);
    //...
}
```

the `callbackData_t type` looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  status_t         status;     // callback status  
  union
  {   
    sync_t          rxSync;     
    rxInfo_t        rxData;    
  }params;

}callbackData_t;
```

`rxInfo_t` is like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   UINT32       dataInfo;       
}rxInfo_t;
```

and `rxData_t` struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   UINT16 *data_p;  // pointer to data

}rxData_t;
```

Now, in my library provided callback, I need to read out the data from `data_p` within `dataPacket`, so I have tried to do

```
void callbackRX(event_t ID, callbackData_t *callbackData_p){
    rxData_t *dataPacket = (rxData_t *)(callbackData_p->params.rxInfo.dataInfo);
    // Read first byte of data from the data pointer
    int test;
    test = dataPacket->data_p[0];
```

}

but the number I get is just a very big integer, like e.g. 14236, and I am supposed to read out 256, since the received data should be 73 byte large array, starting from `256` and counts up to `512`, `1024` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the pointer to point to your actual data.

For example:

```
typedef struct
{
   UINT16 *data_p;  // pointer to data

}rxData_t

...

  UINT16 buff[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  rxData_t my_data;
  my_data.data_p = buff;
  printf ("data[0]= %d\n", my_data.data_p[0]);
```

Comment: How could this access the data within `*dataPacket`? I think there is something essential I don't understand from the casting that is done. Are all `data_p` pointing to the same variabel when you define a struct of the `rxData_t` type? Could you please elaborate a bit why this work? Thank you, and +1 for fast answer!

Comment: In your code, 1) rxData_t is just a struct that contains a pointer, 2) the pointer is "data_p", and 3) *nowhere* in your code do I see where the buffer that "data_p" should point to.  SUGGESTION: if your library's documentation doesn't help you, perhaps look at variables and hex memory locations in your debugger.

Comment: So my solution was correct then, and you answered the title question but not my specific one? As I said, the library just gives me this strict which I am supposed to read in the callback, but if I am already doing this correctly, I should start looking at memory locations as you suggest